# How do I add a Kivy drop-down menu made in the .py file from the .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to have a button in a specific screen that will open a drop-down menu below that button. I got it to work when I built the drop-down menu in the .kv file, but the problem is that I need to build the menu with items from a list that I made in the .py file.  When I try to reference that list in the .kv file, it gives me an error saying that the list is not defined.  So I built the drop-down list in the .py file, then added a function inside the screen's class that returns the menu, and I put that function in the button in the .kv file.  The problem is that when I press the button, nothing happens.  Does anyone know how to get the menu to show?

.py:

```
...

drop = DropDown()
for i in range(1, len(exercises)):
    btn = Button(text=exercises[i][0], size_hint_y= None, size=(50,50))
    drop.add_widget(btn)
...

class AddExerciseScreen(Screen):
    def show_object(self):

        return drop

class LightweightApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
        sm.add_widget(TimerScreen(name='timerscreen'))
        sm.add_widget(AddExerciseScreen(name='addexercise'))
       

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LightweightApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
...
<AddExerciseScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "Menu"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width* 0.2, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.5, root.height*0.95
        on_release: root.show_object()
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
def show_object(self):

    return drop
```

with:

```
def show_object(self):

    drop.open()
```

Comment: When I tried drop.open(), it gave me an error: TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'

Comment: Then change it to `drop.open(self)`.

Comment: That does fix the error, but the menu still doesn't show when I click the button.